# How to change value of column in devexpress gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspxgridview

Hi I want to change value or text of TankLevel1 column in gridview.

If TankLevel1 equal to 0 I want to display "Tank 1 is offline" on TankLevel1 column.

I tried like this 
TankLevel1 is integer in SQL

```
<dx:GridViewDataProgressBarColumn  
    Settings-AllowAutoFilter=False Settings-AllowGroup=False Settings-AllowSort=False  FieldName="TankLevel1" Caption="Tank Level 1">

    <PropertiesProgressBar Width="" Height=""/>
    <Settings AllowAutoFilter="False" AllowSort="False" AllowGroup="False"/>
</dx:GridViewDataProgressBarColumn>
```

```
protected void myGrid_CustomColumnDisplayText(object sender, ASPxGridViewColumnDisplayTextEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column.FieldName == "TankLevel1 ") return;
    if (e.Value.Equals(50))
    {
        e.DisplayText = "Tank 1 is offline";
    }
}
```

Comment: You return from method if fieldName is TankLevel1?

Comment: Yes.I want to replace 0 or some text for value of TankLevel1 column when it is equal to 50.I can change for GridViewDataTextColumn but it is not working for GridViewDataProgressBarColumn.

Comment: And my question is here https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q552108

Comment: How can you change column text when you quit method if column.FieldName equals TankLevel1? Shouldn't you change `== "TankLevel1 "` to `"!= "TankLevel1 "`?

Comment: I tried "!= "TankLevel1 " but it is not working.